# Putting ui attributes on domain model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My web application currently has a domain model and a view model. Domain model is almost a representation of my database. So when I insert data into a table, i'm inserting my domain model object. My view model handles how I want to display my ui. So if i have a property on view model that has a drop down list, i give it a custom display attribute drop down list with an enum saying what kind of values to load ([DropDownList(Enums.Product)]. My view model also has display labels and calls specific editor templates for the different properties using UIHint. I feel like creating a view model is becoming repetitive. I'm wondering if there's any harm in just putting display attributes (uihint, display(name="blah")) right on my domain model so i can skip the view model unless specifically need it for something. The only other solution is to actually wite out the html so that i'm using Html.Editor("SomeProperty", Model.SomeProperty) instead of Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty). Any thoughts?

Comment: No, continue using view models. I admit it can seem a little repetitive at times, but that's because you are working with similar but still very much different things. It's totally inappropriate to add UI logic to your entities and it *will* bite you if you go done that path.

Comment: Thats what I assumed, its just so repetitive.

Comment: I don't personally follow the approach because I prefer to keep my entities and view models distinct, but I've seen many who will simply create a view model that wraps around the entity, allowing you to put the view specific code on the view model and then reference the entity directly as a property for the actual data. However, that can still be tricky if you need to customize properties such as making a field required in one view while optional in another. I'm not recommending the approach per se, but it's something you can investigate for some of your more straight-forward scenariors.